# emacs-ipython-notebook and SCIMAX

Tags: python, emacs, ipython

I was wondering what is best from these two enablers of interactive python or `iPython`. Either using `emacs-ipython-notebook` or `SCIMAX`. I understand that both accomplish quite the same thing, but can't decide which one to use and have no time to start checking. So if someone has checked already, much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Scimax** is a complete emacs distro. Meaning a complete Emacs environment, a complete setup.  If that is what you are after, it is well maintained by jkitchin in: https://github.com/jkitchin/scimax

**EIN** (Emacs ipython Notebook) maintained [here](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-ipython-notebook), Is a notebook solution. little configuration is required. It is a package like any Emacs package.

**org-babel** Worth mentioning too, look for `ob-python` or `ob-ipython`, if you are using `org` it is a natural way to include code the literate way. It is what I ended up using . Have a look at:

https://github.com/gregsexton/ob-ipython

And also at:

https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html

Comment: Thanks so much, manandearth. As I understand, Scimax uses org-babel to generate the jupyter o ipython outlook, is this correct?

Comment: Yes. It is a complete package for scientific programming and publishing. It is an overkill for my use ( I use some data-science but mostly programming) I recommend you try org-babel first, to see if you like the workflow. It is different to a notebook and I find that its flexibility is a bonus, yet If you like jupyter notebooks then EIN is your better bet.

Comment: Thanks again. What would you say the main difference is between using babel and EIN? I suppose, with babel you just specify where to get output as opposed to EIN? Not sure.

Comment: If you are familiar with `Jupyter-notebooks`, then `EIN` is just that: Input output and markdown blocks. It comes packed with functions for evaluating and navigating and more. `Org Babel` brings the organisation of` Org` files, which is much bigger than markdown plus a specific configurable syntax for code blocks. Many languages are supported as well as `noweb`, sessions, `tangling` which outputs a file from all the codeblocks that are marked as tangled.. and much more. It requires configuration for your specific needs, what makes it more flexible and less out-of-the-box.

Comment: Thanks, just as I thought. You've been very helpful.